How can Paul's words in 1 Corinthians 7 be interpreted without antinatalist implications?
(1 Corinthians 7:8) "To the unmarried and the widows I say that it is good for them to remain single, as I am"
(1 Corinthians 7:32-34) "The unmarried man is anxious about the things of the Lord, how to please the Lord. 33 But the married man is anxious about worldly things, how to please his wife, 34 and his interests are divided. And the unmarried or betrothed woman is anxious about the things of the Lord, how to be holy in body and spirit. But the married woman is anxious about worldly things, how to please her husband."
(1 Corinthians 7:38) "So then he who marries his betrothed does well, and he who refrains from marriage will do even better"
Here is the antinatalist implication of these verses. If we follow Paul's advice and stay single and childless, then humanity would go extinct (because nobody will replenish the population). But the doctrine that argues for human extinction (antinatalism) is widely regarded by Christians to be a false one. The implication that the "ideal" scenario is the one where humans die out is an incredibly repugnant one.
So my question is, how can Christians interpret 1 Corinthians 7 to avoid all of these implications: 1) it is better for humanity to go extinct 2) it is better to be single 3) it is better to be childless?

If at first you don't succeed (in Christianity) try again (in Hermeneutics)? "This is exactly the answer I was looking for", to the only answer, very recently posted. Telling. Please go to the Tour section for newcomers and understand how both those sites are meant to operate.

Yeah, because I didn't find any of the answers over at Christianity SE to be convincing. And I happened to like this one. I am not sure what you are insinuating here

This question is unsuitable for this site. It isn't asking about the intended meaning of the scripture, it is asking "How can Christians…?". Even worse, the implications it asks about are based on your misunderstanding. A good question for this site would ask what Paul meant without even mentioning any implications for Christians.

Sure, I will reword my title to make it better reflect this website

Superflash, suggest you rephrase as "In 1 Cor. 7:26, does Paul mean to say men should never marry?"  Context is part of hermeneutics, and has to be taken into account.

On the second thought, rewording the title to be specifically about 26th verse was not actually what my question was about. If anything, I was more concerned about verses 8 and 38. But your answer answers the question that I had, so it's all good.

I’m voting to close this question because questions scoped to particular groups belong on Christianity.

I don't think this question is scoped to any particular groups of people.

The key is knowing the time and historical background of these sentiments.  Paul was writing to the Corinthians about 55 AD. (DatingTheNewTestament)  He was looking into their very near future for the coming war with Rome and the destruction of Jerusalem and that old Mosaic temple. These sentiments were not commands, but helpful warnings for their survival.
Paul knew that it was going to be very hard times of the persecution under both the Sanhedrin and the Roman rule under Nero.  It would be very hard to run to the mountains as Jesus had told them to do in Matt. 24:16 if they had a family and young children to carry.
These verses are not meant for all Christians for every generation.  Paul was speaking to those Christians of the 1st century AD as they were the ones who would have to try to survive the tribulations and persecutions which were about to play out in Judea and Jerusalem.
It is very necessary to read and study the scriptures from the first audience perspective.  The prophecies of Matt. 24, Mark 13, Luke 21, and all of Revelation (John's Olivet discourse) were for the destruction of Jerusalem which was still about 15 years in their future.

21 then those in Judea, let them flee to the mountains; and those in her midst, let them depart out; and those in the countries, let them not come in to her; 22 because these are days of vengeance, to fulfil all things that have been written. (Luke 21:21-22, YLT)

This was specifically prophesied for those living in Judea in the 1st century AD, warning them of the Roman armies that would surround Jerusalem in the Roman-Jewish war of AD 67-70.  The time period of that prophecy belonged to those of that generation, not to our generation.
While the general statements and commands are meant for people of all generations, the specific instructions are centered on those of their generation.  They may have some application at other time periods of other wars and hardships, but they are not meant to say that men should never marry.
Further discussion:
When Does "You" Mean "Me"?
The Signs of Revelation - Part I: The Time of His Coming
Testing The Spirits - Part II: The End

It would be very hard to run to the mountains as Jesus had told them to do in Matt. 24:16 if they had a family and young children to carry - this makes absolutely 0 sense when looking at 1 Cor 7:32-34 where Paul specifically gave his rationale for celibacy: it lets unmarried men and women focus on God. Paul never says a single word about a concern about "carrying young children"

Context is a part of hermeneutics.  Paul's concern was their immediate circumstances.  While an unmarried man or woman can be more focused on God, to take that as the only reason for Paul's statement then would contradict God's command to marry and have children.  The scriptures must harmonize! using 1 scripture in a way that contradicts another is wrong & does not constitute correct hermeneutics.

By “and all of Revelation (John's Olivet discourse) were for the destruction of Jerusalem” are you implying the belief that all of Revelation has already come to pass, even Jesus’ second coming, or did you intend to restrict that statement more than you did? Overall this is a good answer (in particular the message of considering historical and cultural context) but if you mean by this what I think you might, I can’t upvote.

Answer
Christians can rest assured that there are no implications of antinatalism in 1 Corinthians 7.
Explanation
1 Corinthians chapter 7 has 3 different sections; in other words, it deals with 3 different topics of human life. Let us see each of them.

Married Couples

The believers in Corinth wrote to Paul asking certain things and Paul is replying to them.

“Now I will answer the questions that you asked in your
letter. You asked, "Is it best for people not to marry?" (verse 1; CEV).

Many people misunderstand the first verse as an instruction from Paul! But in fact Paul is just quoting their statement and question.
God’s Command
Paul is very much aware of God’s command regarding marriage:

“And God blessed them; and God said to them, Be fruitful and multiply,
and fill the earth, and subdue it, and rule over the fish of the seas,
and over birds of the heavens, and over all beasts creeping on the
earth” (Gen 1:28: repeated several times).


“Therefore, a man shall leave his father and his mother, and shall
cleave to his wife and they shall become one flesh” (Gen 2:24).

So, Paul says this regarding marriage:

“For the wife does not have authority over her own body, but the
husband does. Likewise the husband does not have authority over his
own body, but the wife does. Do not deprive one another, except
perhaps by agreement for a limited time, that you may devote
yourselves to prayer; but then come together again” (verses 4-5).

This is Paul verifying and agreeing to God’s command.
But in verse 6, Paul gives his personal opinion regarding the unmarried people.

“I tell you this not as an order, but simply as a
permission………..Now, to the unmarried and to the widows I say that it
would be better for you to continue to live alone as I do” (verses 6,
8).

But why does the Apostle give this special permission not as an order?
We will see the answer later.

Social Status

The second issue is regarding the status of each believer in life. This is rather uncontroversial in its application.
A circumcised man should not become uncircumcised and the latter should not become circumcised. A slave is free as far as the Lord is concerned and the free is a slave to the Lord.
Yet, Paul advises the slaves to become free if they can.

The Unmarried & Widowed

The third issue is concerning the unmarried and the widowed. Paul says clearly that he is not giving the divine command but his opinion based on the discernment guided by the Holy Spirit in him.

“Now, concerning what you wrote about unmarried people: I do not have
a command from the Lord, but I give my opinion as one who by the
Lord's mercy is worthy of trust” (verse 25).

So, what is his opinion in good trust?

“Considering the present distress (G318: anagkē), I think it is
better for a man to stay as he is…….What I mean, my friends, is this:
there is not much time left” (verses 26, 29).

So, that’s it.
This is not a permanent order from God but a temporary adjustment considering the present distress.
What Distress
So, what is the present distress Paul is talking about?
As Gina has pointed out correctly, Paul is talking about the persecution that was going on at the time. (There was growing tension between militant Jews and the Roman army in Jerusalem).

“How terrible it will be in those days for women who are pregnant
and for mothers with little babies! Terrible distress (G318:
anagkē) will come upon this land, and God's punishment will fall on
this people” (Luke 21:23).

So, this is the reason why Paul gave the “opinion” with good common sense that married couples, especially mothers, will have terrible time in great calamity.
So, better remain single for a short time.
Conclusion
What Paul advises in 1 Corinthians chapter 7, is an ad-hoc arrangement for a short while.
It is not a divine command against marriage and child bearing!

Really love your answer as well!

Thank you, SuperFlash.

+1 Excellent answer using context! Jesus had a similar statement in Matt. 19:10-12 NASB - The disciples *said to Him, “If the relationship of the man with his wife is like this, it is better not to marry.” But He said to them, “Not all men can accept this statement, but only those to whom it has been given. For there are eunuchs who were born that way from their mother’s womb; and there are eunuchs who were made eunuchs by people; and there are also eunuchs who made themselves eunuchs for the sake of the kingdom of heaven. The one who is able to accept this, let him accept it." Choice/Called.

Appreciate your supporting comment, Dieter.

Not sure about attributing Paul's "difficulties" to Christian persecution in the 1st century CE. He clearly alludes to the end of the world in 1 Cor 7:31: For the present form of this world is passing away

@ Nephesh Roi I think Avi Abraham has a good point. 1 Cor 7:31 indeed kind of goes against your answer. Do you have any responses?

Yes, 3 things. First, jumping to quick conclusions is not advisable. Secondly, Paul says that he has not given any hint by spirit, or by word or by letter (epistle) that the end of the world is nearby (2 Thes 2:2). So that much is sure. Thirdly, regarding 1 Cor 7:31, please note it doesn’t mention anything about the end of the word. It says, “those who deal in material goods, as though they were not fully occupied with them. For this world, as it is now, will not last much longer” (GNB).

It simply means the then and now existing “selfish” fashion (in Greek, the “scheme”, i.e., the “get attitude”) of the present world was passing away. Besides, Paul was aware that Jesus prophesied that the Jews “shall be led away captive into all nations. And Jerusalem shall be trodden down by the nations until the times (in plural) of the nations is fulfilled” (Luke 21:24). And Paul knew that it takes time for the Jews to be scattered into ALL nations (Rom 11:25).
